# react-native-image-picker crashing at run - Metro Bundler error

Tags: ios, react-native, package-managers, react-native-image-picker, metro-bundler

I want to use 'react-native-image-picker' in my application. After importing and following the install instructions from the github instructions. I get a metro bundler crash on run. It can't seem to locate the 'react-image-picker' or it's dependencies?

I have tried initializing a new project and ONLY installing image picker. I have tried running 'react-native link' and 'react-native link react-native-image-picker' in the root. I have tried initializing the project with expo. I've checked the directories that Metro claims are missing, and they look good to me.

```
import React from 'react';
import {
  StyleSheet,
  ScrollView,
  View,
  Text,
  Button
} from 'react-native';
import ImagePicker from 'react-native-image-picker';

const options = {
  title: 'Select Avatar',
  customButtons: [{ name: 'fb', title: 'Choose Photo from Facebook' }],
  storageOptions: {
    skipBackup: true,
    path: 'images',
  },
};

const App = () => {
  return (
    <Button title="Select Image" onPress={() => {
      ImagePicker.showImagePicker(options, (response) => {console.log('Response = ', response);})
    }} />
  );
};
```

error: bundling failed: Error: While trying to resolve module `react-native-image-picker` from file `/Users/owenmorris/Documents/GitHub/fecebook/App.js`, the package `/Users/owenmorris/Documents/GitHub/fecebook/node_modules/react-native-image-picker/package.json` was successfully found. However, this package itself specifies a `main` module field that could not be resolved (`/Users/owenmorris/Documents/GitHub/fecebook/node_modules/react-native-image-picker/src/index.ts`. Indeed, none of these files exist:

- `/Users/owenmorris/Documents/GitHub/fecebook/node_modules/react-native-image-picker/src/index.ts(.native||.ios.js|.native.js|.js|.ios.json|.native.json|.json|.ios.ts|.native.ts|.ts|.ios.tsx|.native.tsx|.tsx)`
- `/Users/owenmorris/Documents/GitHub/fecebook/node_modules/react-native-image-picker/src/index.ts/index(.native||.ios.js|.native.js|.js|.ios.json|.native.json|.json|.ios.ts|.native.ts|.ts|.ios.tsx|.native.tsx|.tsx)`
  at ResolutionRequest.resolveDependency (/Users/owenmorris/Documents/GitHub/fecebook/node_modules/metro/src/node-haste/DependencyGraph/ResolutionRequest.js:65:15)
  at DependencyGraph.resolveDependency (/Users/owenmorris/Documents/GitHub/fecebook/node_modules/metro/src/node-haste/DependencyGraph.js:283:16)
  at Object.resolve (/Users/owenmorris/Documents/GitHub/fecebook/node_modules/metro/src/lib/transformHelpers.js:264:42)
  at /Users/owenmorris/Documents/GitHub/fecebook/node_modules/metro/src/DeltaBundler/traverseDependencies.js:399:31
  at Array.map ()
  at resolveDependencies (/Users/owenmorris/Documents/GitHub/fecebook/node_modules/metro/src/DeltaBundler/traverseDependencies.js:396:18)
  at /Users/owenmorris/Documents/GitHub/fecebook/node_modules/metro/src/DeltaBundler/traverseDependencies.js:269:33
  at Generator.next ()
  at asyncGeneratorStep (/Users/owenmorris/Documents/GitHub/fecebook/node_modules/metro/src/DeltaBundler/traverseDependencies.js:87:24)
  at _next (/Users/owenmorris/Documents/GitHub/fecebook/node_modules/metro/src/DeltaBundler/traverseDependencies.js:107:9)
  BUNDLE  [ios, dev] ./index.js ░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░ 0.0% (0/1), failed.

Comment: restart the metro bundler by re-run `react-native start`

Comment: I was able to get Metro to build and launch my app in the simulator, but now I'm back to "unable to locate 'react-native-image-picker'" with suggestions for run 'react-native link react-native-image-picker' which I've done, and it still doesn't work. It just can't seem to load the image picker for some reason.

Comment: I read more on the react-native-image-picker community github, and some people with similar problems had luck with rolling back their version. I tried this rollback, and it fixed locating the depencencies, but now "null is not an object: (evaluating 'ImagePickerManager.showImagePicker')"

Answer (score 1):

I also faced the similar issue with latest release. I changed the version to 0.28.0.

```
npm install react-native-image-picker@0.28.0
npx react-native link react-native-image-picker
```

Please see if it works for you.

Answer (score 0):

the answer is [here](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-image-picker/issues/1165)

simply is:

2. Second solution

Import library from lib/common/js
import ImagePicker from 'react-native-image-picker/lib/commonjs';